# Cannot call alias within bash script

Tags: bash, macos

I have a file called `~/.gotorc` and in it I have

```
alias goto_usr="cd /usr"
alias goto_bin="cd /user/local/bin"
```

Then in my `.zshrc` I have

```
source ~/.gotorc
goto() {
    `goto_$1`
}
```

But when I run `goto bin`, it says `goto:bin: command not found: goto_bin`. But if I run `goto_bin` then it works and I go to the expected folder.

How come?

Comment: `.zshrc` is used with `zsh`, not `bash`. You want to use `.bashrc` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of aliases you can define a single function `goto` like this:

```
goto() {
    case "$1" in
       usr)
       cd /usr;;
       bin)
       cd /usr/local/bin;;
    esac
}
```

Then use it as:

```
goto usr
goto bin
```